# How do I define my own hardcoded Ceilings and Floors in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some sql statements that calculates some numbers. It's possible (with bonus points/penalty points) that a person could get a final score OVER 100 (with bonus points) or 
UNDER 0 (with penalties).

How can i make sure that the value calculated, if it exceeds 100 it get's maxed at 100. Alternatively, if the score ends up being below 0, then it's min'd at 0.

I'm assuming I could use a simple UDF that does this math - that's not hard. I'm not sure if this already exists?

I checked out [CEILING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx) and [MAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx) and both of these are doing other things, not what I'm after.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tes, it would be nice if SQL Server had the ANSI-SQL "horizontal" aggregate functions, then you could do exactly what the others have suggested: "*MIN(Score, 100)*", etc.  Sadly, it doesn't so you cannot do it that way.

The typical way to do this is with CASE expressions:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Score BETWEEN 0 AND 100 THEN Score
        WHEN Score < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE 100 END as BoundScore
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Would there be a performance penalty if that case statement was in a scalar-valued function?

Comment: Yes.  Not sure how much, but it's usually significant for large rowsets.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the score is stored in a column in a table, or is there some calculated total with these constraints?

In general, probably the easiest would be to put the logic into a trigger that would check to see what value is being inserted, and change it to your max or min if it's out of bounds.

Or, what I would do is use whatever abstraction level is inserting the value do the checking, since it's not a database integrity issue, but an application validation issue.

Comment: The scores are being calculated and have not been stored in any table fields (yet). I already have a check constraint on the field which will hold the final value. But i was wondering if custom scalar functions (aka UDF) would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger is indeed the correct (and only solution).

You need a trigger which fires BEFORE both UPDATE and INSERT (or two separate triggers, one for UPDATE and one for INSERT).  Simply check the proposed new value for that column, and push it up or down if necessary.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(SQL.80).aspx

The constraint becomes optional, but is very strongly recommended.

Comment: I also can't see why a trigger is the only solution here? Why? I am doing the math/calculations in a select query. So why can't i fix up the result, there, BEFORE i save the result to some table?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a trigger then how about

MIN(MAX(XXX, 0), 100)  where XXX is whatever existing code you have to calculate a score.

eg: MIN(MAX(enemiesKilled+10*LivesLeft+*15*sum(PrincessRescued), 0), 100)

Comment: that's what i thought also .. but MIN/MAX only accepts one arg... ???? like wa???